# Highchart xAxis plotbad with specific heigth

Tags: highcharts

I have three plotband plotted using xaxis . In case these plotband overlaps i want to show the difference clearly . Is there any  such possibility to show the overlapping clearly . Or is there any possibility to  draw plotband with specific height. 
Please help.

Comment: Can you please share the code which you have tried till now

Comment: I have implemented something similar to this : http://jsfiddle.net/ahw94/1/

Comment: You cannot set heght of plotbands, but you can use renderer to add this shape in any place and any width/height. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer

Answer (score 0):

As said above there is no direct way to limit the height of the Plot Band. 
Internally the Plot Band is rendered as path attribute. What I did is, I just wrapped the path attribute with  (using jquery) wherein specifying the width and height required . This worked !!! May be it will be useful for some one.